# text/html in a jTextPane, NetBeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, hyperlink, jtextpane

I started using NetBeans today, and it was all going swimmingly, until I came upon this block.

I'm trying to make my jTextPane format any HTML i have in it. I've tried changing the Content type in the code with `jTextPane1.setContentType("text/html");` but to no avail.
I've also tried changing the properties in the Design Window to relevant values, but no luck there either.

After some googling, I saw that Netbeans had a bug before that wouldn't let text/html content be enabled properly, but it has been resolved a couple versions back.

Have any ideas how i can enable html in the panes? or even just another way to get hyperlinks working.

Comment: BTW - what does a `JTextPane` bring to this that is missing from a `JEditorPane`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i use a JEditorPane for exact the same pupose. 
Just set the ContentType to "text/html" as you allready do and you are good to go.

To include some predefined stylesheets i use this code:

```
editorPane.setContentType("text/html");
HTMLEditorKit kit = new HTMLEditorKit();
editorPane.setEditorKit(kit);
File cssfile = new File("src/Assets/code.css");

StyleSheet styleSheet = kit.getStyleSheet();
styleSheet.importStyleSheet(cssfile.toURI().toURL());

editorPane.setText("<html><head></head><body><pre></pre></body></html>");
```

You can use setEditable(false) so the HTML cant be changed.

Just tryed it with Netbeans 7.2 beta and it works the same way with an JTextPane.

Here is some more Docu about it:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html#recap

Comment: Also take a look at the bottom of this page: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html HTMLEditorKit is *not assigned* to JTextPane by default.

Comment: To get Links working you have to write an LinkController. See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLEditorKit.LinkController.html

Comment: +1, learned something, real quick regarding `JEditorPane/JTextPane`

Comment: thanks so much :) I was so focussed on getting a text pane working, I didn't look at other options

Comment: Thank you!  All these other threads I found showed how to do this for JTextArea or JScrollPane, but they didn't work in my netbeans-created GUI.  No idea why, but in netbeans, seems like one has to go through the editor pane!